# Best control with image and onClick to call javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

What is the best control which can display image, call javascript and do it without postback? maybe even change an image on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `<img>` tag.

Comment: but tell me pls how to add hover to that img?

Comment: You can use jQuery's `hover` event, or manually add `mouseover` and `mouseout` handlers

Answer (score 0):

A HTML Element of your choice I suppose:

```
<div style="background: pink url(/image.png);" onclick="alert('javascript')">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
div:hover {
    background: lightgreen url(/image2.png);
}
```